# How should Cordova plugin for single platform be packaged?

Tags: plugins, cordova

**Background**

I am developing a Cordova app that must run as a service, i.e. continue in the background and restart when the device does. As far as I can tell, on iOS it is just a case of setting the UIBackgroundModes correctly but on Android requires a little more effort and the service needs to be explicitly started.

I have developed a plugin for Android based on Mark Taylor's example [here](http://red-folder.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/phonegap-service-tutorial-part-1.html).

At present I have some JS called on `deviceready` to start the Android code but don't need to do anything for iOS.

**Question**

How should I package my plugin so that it will work on all platforms with zero config. It seems clunky to write `if (Device.type == 'android')` statements in my main JS but I don't really want to write native null implementations.

Is there a suggested approach for this?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out using the `<js-module>` tag described [here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/plugin_ref_spec.md.html#Plugin%20Specification).

Added this to my `plugin.xml`:

```
<platform name='android'>
    ...
    <js-module src="androidSpecificStuff.js" name="SomeModule">
        <clobbers target="SomeModule" />
    </js-module>
    ...
</platform>
```

Then in `androidSpecificStuff.js` had code like:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
    // do android-specific initialisation here  
})
```